# Array Field for a Content Type. Is it possible?

Tags: entities

I'm new in drupal and I'm about to use drupal for my expanding site.
This is my issue:
I have some documents which segmented to sentences and words and each word has a tag for example:

Document: 
   This is a test text to show what I say. This is the second sentence. This is the third.
Sentences: 
   1. This is a test text to show what I say
   2. This is the second sentence
and so on.

Tagged words: 
   This => ABC
   is => DEF
   a => EE
   test => NME
and so on.

I would like to make a node for each document not each word or sentence and store sentences and words as fields.
This data is stored in a mysql database and I can export it in any form.
How can I implement this structure in Drupal?
Is there any module for it? or I should develop a new module?
or any other solution?

Thank you all so much

Comment: You'll get a better response if you phrase your question title more specifically.

Comment: So you would want "Tagged words" as set of name, value pairs, is it?

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to store complete array as a single input in a field, you can do so by serialize the array.

Create a long text field and serialize the array before input by calling hook_node_submit().

Answer (score 0):

Create a new content type (at /admin/structure/types/ in D7). Add the fields you want within it. Then write a template or create a view to output the fields in the order you desire.

Comment: ok but how can I create an array of words as a field?

Comment: I don't think you can, with the default set of fields. You'd need to search drupal.org for a module which provides an array-like field.

Comment: You can thank by click the up arrow next to my response :)

Comment: You can thank @tog22 even more by clicking the little tick ;-)

Comment: come on guys :D That Thank you was for replying not for that reply :P

Answer (score 0):

Create a text field with multiple possible values and programatically save your datas as $i number values

```
 $node = new stdClass ();
 $node->type = 'our content type';
 $node->your_field ['und'] [$i] ['value'];
 ...

node_save ( $node );
```

for associative array , field collection module could do